# A question about rounding corners in this situation

Tags: icon

I have a rectangle cut from in the middle diagonally. The cutting stroke is rounded. So the rectangle edges should also be rounded I felt. The question here is, do I round the top-left and bottom-right corners or all corners that are made due to the cutting?

**Here's a quick video (converted to GIF) I made to better explain things (ignore the "pattern," it was unintentional while converting):**

[image: Video to explain my question]

Basically, here are the different versions:
[image: The variations to choose from, with different corners]

Comment: I'd say it depends on the effect you want to apply. If you want your square to be seen as cut in the middle, I wouldn't round the top-right and bottom-left corners.
BUT... I find the option 3 more aesthetically pleasing thanks to the rounded corners (completely subjective of course).
Maybe if the "cut" was larger you could round every corner? Something like this: https://i.imgur.com/rhzmMRY.png (sorry if the comment is too noisy, just trying so share my useless thoughts :D)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not really,

- the shadow of the stroke indicates that it's above the square
- the width of the stroke together with its shadow is wider than the rounded edge and hides it

[image]

If the top shape has rounded corners it will make a separate entity, it will no longer be a square with a stroke on it but two triangles and a stroke:

[image]